# ColdFusion cfhttp.filecontent

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cfhttp

I recently started learning coldfusion. I am getting a bit confused, reading through numerous websites regarding the function cfhttp.filecontent.

Can any of you help me understand and provide me with an example of how I would format the following code I am writing? I am already grabbing name and email from a form on the index page and trying to initiate an API request and get the password back, formatted correctly.

```
<cfset passwordcomplexity = 4>
<cfinclude template='header.cfm'>
    
    <cfhttp method="GET" url="https://hardest.pw/api/#passwordlenght#/#passwordcomplexity#">

    <cfset returnString = cfhttp.filecontent>
            
    <cfdump var="#returnString#">
        
    <!---<cfmail to="#form.email#"
    from="no-reply@training-pavel.com"
    subject="New random password"
    type="text">
    Hey there, #form.name#!

    We've just generated a new password for you! You can see it below:
        
        
</cfmail>--->
<cfinclude template='footer.cfm'>
```

At the end I just get something like this:

```
{"code":200,"desc":"Command completed successfully","password":"[&Vo4%T#l8","hardestlink":"https:\/\/hardest.pw\/0758828a-a6f6-4f9b-9bd7-c0dc778de0b7"}
```

Comment: `<cfset returnStruct = deserializeJSON(cfhttp.filecontent)><cfdump var="#returnStruct.password#">` will get you the password.

Comment: Is `#passwordlenght#` spelled wrong?

Comment: @JamesAMohler Yes it is.

Comment: Also, **never store or email plain text passwords**.  Passwords should be hashed.  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120540/why-shouldnt-i-store-passwords-in-plaintext